# How to make a UIButton do two things at once?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit

How can I make a `UIButton` complete two separate methods when pressed?

Answer (score 6):

If you're designing your view controller in an Interface Builder (either storyboard or xib), we can hook our button up to as many actions as we want.

Using the ctrl+drag method, we create a method to handle the button press:

[image]

And we can hook up as many methods to as many different actions as we want:

[image]

Here, this button is connected to three different methods.

---

We can do the same thing in code programmatically.

In Swift:

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action: "methodOne:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
myButton.addTarget(self, action: "methodTwo:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
myButton.addTarget(self, action: "methodThree:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
```

Or in Objective-C:

```
[myButton addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(methodOne:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[myButton addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(methodTwo:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[myButton addTarget:self 
             action:@selector(methodThree:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

We can hook up any number of events.

---

As a final note, I'm not sure there's any way to actually control the order in which the methods hooked up directly to the button are called.  In this case, I hooked up the button to the methods in order: `one`, `two`, `three`, but they appeared to be called in a different order: `one`, `three`, `two`.  They are consistently called in this order.

If it the order is actually important, then we should be hooking up our button just to a single method which then calls all the other methods in the explicit order we need:

```
@IBAction func buttonPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.methodOne(sender)
    self.methodTwo(sender)
    self.methodThree(sender)
}
```

And to be honest, I'd say this should be the recommended approach anyway.  It probably makes the source code a little easier to read.

Comment: Thank you! But when I try to do this, it forms a new connection to the button, and gets disconnected from my previous acton. How did you make it link more the one time?

Comment: Are you connecting actions or outlets?

Comment: I'm making Actions. It lets me make both an action and n outlet per button, but not two of the same.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you on? I didn't have to do anything special to do this.

Comment: I'm on version 6. I also have the latest beta